# comparison between the elements of list with keys of dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to check if a particular key is present in some dictionary. I can use has_key ?? Is there any other method to compare  the items of the list to the key of dictionary.

I have a list like...[(3,4),(4,5)..]
I need to check if the (3,4) is there in the dictionary.

Comment: `has_key()` is deprecated in higher versions of Python 2 and has been removed from Python 3. Use Michael Anderson's solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "right" way is using the `in` operator like what the other answers have mentioned. This works for anything iterable and you get some speed gains when you can look things up by hashing (like for dictionaries and sets). There's also an older way which works only for dictionaries which is the `has_key` method. I don't usually see it around these days and it's slower as well (though not by much).

```
>>> timeit.timeit('f = {(1,2) : "Foo"}; f.has_key((1,2))')
0.27945899963378906
>>> timeit.timeit('f = {(1,2) : "Foo"}; (1,2) in f')
0.22165989875793457
```

Answer (score 4):

Something like this?

```
>>> d = { (1,3):"foo", (2,6):"bar" }
>>> print (1,3) in d
True
>>> print (1,4) in d
False
>>> L = [ (1,3), (1,4), (15) ]
>>> print [ x in d for x in L ]
[True, False, False]
```

If you want to add missing entries you'll need an explicit loop

```
for x in L:
  if x not in d:
    d[x]="something"
```

Comment: what if, I want to check, if a key is available in the dictinary or not...if not...then add that key to the dic...??

Comment: That's a new question, but take a look at the `setdefault()` method. http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=setdefault#dict.setdefault

Comment: how about update method.I think, if the key is already there in the dictionary, it will put another value of that key, so we get multiple entries thru update method.

Answer (score 0):

`dictionary.keys()` returns a list of keys
you can then use `if (3,4) in d.keys()`

Comment: No need. The `in` operator when applied to a dictionary will look in the dict's keys.